# Capture traffic from virtualbox emulating android with fiddler in windows 10 local machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, fiddler

I'm emulating an android x86 on my virtualbox and I want to capture traffic with fiddler in the local machine (windows 10) how can I do that? thanks

Comment: I'm with the same problem as well, Fiddler isn't capturing the VM's output.

Comment: hey, as I said on a previous comment, I had the same problem, but I solved it! And I answered your question an year ago, please check it out and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect the *proxy* of your Android's wi-fi. To do that you need to get some information from **Fiddler** and use them to configure **Android x86**.

*(also that works for real devices on the same connection as Fiddler's, but don't do that with your personal device - also you'll need root on your real device)*

---

### Fiddler

1. Go to settings:

> [image: location of Fiddler's settings button]

2. Configure Fiddler's HTTPS options:

> [image: Fiddler's HTTPS options tab]

3. Configure Connections options, set a port and allow remote computers to connect:

> [image: Fiddler's Connections options tab]

4. Get your IP by hovering Fiddler's Online indicator, located at the far bottom-right of the window:

> [image]

---

### Android x86's VM

1. Go to Wi-Fi, tap and hold your current connection and click in "Modify Network":

> [image]

2. Open "Show advanced options" and set your Proxy settings to Manual
3. Type the IP address of your computer and port (usually 8888) of the Fiddler server.

> [image]

4. To verify this configuration, go to http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/. The browser should display the Fiddler Echo Service webpage.
5. Once there, click the FiddlerRoot Certificate link.

> [image]

6. Name the certificate

> [image]

---

After finishing those steps you must be good to go!

Take a look on the original source:

- https://www.andnixsh.com/2017/02/configure-fiddler-for-android-emulator.html